# Word for quadrilateral with no general properties

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

I'd like to know what word to use to talk about a quadrilateral that has no distinctive feature (so, to express it's not a square, not a rectangle, nor rhombus, nor kite, nor parallelogram, nor trapezium/trapezoid.).

For triangles, for instance, the word "scalene" is right. Is it correct for quadrilaterals too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Trapezium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezium)

I guess a *Trapezium* would be your answer as explained [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/trapezium.html).

But do notice that the definition of a *Trapezium* and that of a *Trapezoid* are swapped over in US and UK English usage as explained [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/quadrilaterals.html?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C4429688252).

Comment: Now, to avoid any possible confusion between trapezoid and trapezium, maybe I should use "irregular quadrilateral"?

Comment: @zezollo Yes, as per the linked article, “general irregular quadrilateral” fits best. By the way, your description includes its distinctive features. Just because it's *not* something, doesn't mean it's not something else.

Comment: @zezollo : You can if you wish or you can use either of them according to the version of English used in your country.

Comment: I need something that could be read without ambiguation, whenever possible, in any english-speaking country. Otherwise I'll default to british english I think, but it's an arbitrary choice. Many thanks for the link to http://www.mathopenref.com, it's exactly what I need to find the vocabulary I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, **scalene** means sides of unequal length, which *(actually)* can be a distinctive feature for a shape, e.g. scalene versus equilateral.

You may need to define what you mean by **distinctive**.

**Quadrilateral** is the generic term for a polygon with four sides.
But what determine "distinctive"? Right angles? Equal sides? Convexity?

A four sided shape with unequal sides would be best described as a **quadrilateral** or **polygon**.

Comment: Well, as there may be a lot of possible distinctions (right angles; angles equal by pairs; two or four parallel sides; 2, 3 or 4 equal sides etc.), I will add that it should mean any quadrilateral not being a square, nor rhombus, nor rectangle, nor kite, nor parallelogram, nor trapezium/trapezoid.

Comment: Inconvenient of "quadrilateral": it does not exclude the "special" ones (like squares etc.).

Comment: The main problem is that quadrilaterals have been around for a long time and are very useful, and so a specialised vocabulary has already been developed for them.